# Nging redirect http and https to https://domain (without www)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, 301-redirect

This is my Nginx config:

```
upstream app_server {
  # Bindings to the Gunicorn server
  server 127.0.0.1:8002 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  access_log path_to_nginx-access.log;
  error_log path_to_nginx-error.log;

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name _;
  ssl_certificate path_to_nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key path_to_nginx.key;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root path_to_root;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
      break;
    }
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root path_to_templates;
  }
}
```

with this config I can redirect:

- http://domain.com -> https://domain.com
- https://domain.com -> https://domain.com (same)
- http://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
- https://www.domain.com -> Error

How do I make my server redirect https www to https non-www. 
Keep in mind that I need to handle multiple domains with the same Nginx server (vide server_name).

Thanks!

Comment: With https, you need to have a certificate that covers all the domains you are planning to redirect. You can have a certificate that covers multiple domains, but you need to know all the domains when ordering the certificate. However, it might be possible that nginx cannot use similar `server_name` setup with `https` as you use with `http`, because the domain name is negotiated in a different spot with `https`. So, this might be impossible to achieve.

Comment: Sure! I got you. How would I solve it for one domain only?

Answer (score 1):

For a single domain you can achieve it like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate path_to_certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key path_to_key;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: my certificate only supports domain.com (without wildcards). By adding the code above I'm getting "invalid certificate error". Any tips?

Comment: In that case you need to get a certificate that is valid for both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`. Usually CAs give you certificates that are valid for both. You need to contact your CA and ask how to get a certificate that is valid for both.